# cyclic object value angular2 local storage

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular2 and angular local storage.
I put some key from LS and rewrite it by changed object 
my code:

```
set() {
    this.subscribtions.push(this.selectedUser);
    this.currentUser["subscribtions"] = this.subscribtions;
   /* this.localStorageService.set('currentUser', this.currentUser as User);*/

  }

ngOnInit() {
this.subscribtions = this.localStorageService.get(`user${this.currentUser["first_name_field"]}`)["subscribtions"];}
```

(currentUser and selectedUser are of class User)

```
class User {
 constructor(public first_name_field: string, public second_name_field: string, public  email_field: string, public password_field: string, public dayBirth: number, public monthBirth: number, public  yearBirth: number, public gender: string, public aboutMe: string, public subscribtions: any, public subscribers: any) {
  }
}
```

However I have a mistake: cyclic object value

Who can help?

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation would be to use the spread operator instead of doing a push to the array

```
set() {
    this.subscribtions = [...this.subscribtions, this.selectedUser];
    this.currentUser["subscribtions"] = this.subscribtions;
   /* this.localStorageService.set('currentUser', this.currentUser as User);*/

  }
```

It’s a bad practice to mutate state and that can be the origin of your problem.